# anyone see why my webview is not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I am having trouble getting my webview activity called anyone see what the problem is. I have a list view that is calling another listview but when I click on one of the options in my second listview (which is supposed to open a webview) nothing happens. Thanks for any help

here is my first activity that calls the webview activity

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class AccountingCourses extends ListActivity{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String[] AccClasses = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.AccClasses);
    setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_view, AccClasses));


    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}


    protected void onListItemCick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String account = o.toString();
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("Accounting", account);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
        finish();



    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener (new OnItemClickListener()  {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view) .getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();

            if(position == 0)
            {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), (Fund_Acc.class));
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

And here is my Webview activity

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Fund_Acc extends ListActivity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1); 
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl("http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=2");
}

protected void onListItemCick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Object a = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String Acc100 = a.toString();
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("Fund_Acc", Acc100);
    setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    finish();
}

}
```

webview xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<WebView android:id="@+id/webview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

    />            

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite long way to reproduce your environment to say exactly what happened. First

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener (new OnItemClickListener()
...
    if(position == 0)
    {
      // start Activity with WebView
    }
```

Are you sure position is 0 in your case? Try to setup a breakpoint where you are starting activity, probably it's never called.

Comment: yes its the first choice so therefore 0 right? And I am sorry not sure if I understand what you are saying about break point

Comment: Toggle a breakpoint for this line: Intent myIntent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), (Fund_Acc.class)); Start application in debug mode, click on a first item in list that should start activity with WebView, app's execution process should stop on that breakpoint. Right mouse click on that line, toggle breakpoint.